# Add a class to first query result

Tags: theming, 6

How can I add a class to first query result?

```
$number_of_slides = '3';
$slides_result = db_query_range("SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE tid = 1 ORDER BY nid DESC", array(), 0, $number_of_slides);
while ($slidesid = db_result($slides_result)) {
$slides = node_load($slidesid);
print $slides->title;
}
```

anyway I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('.item')
    .eq(0).addClass('first').end()
    .eq(-1).addClass('last').end();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.first, .last{
background-color:#0099FF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item">aaa</div>
<div class="item">bbb</div>
<div class="item">ccc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery anyway, why not just use the [`.first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`.last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) selectors?

```
$('.item').first().addClass('first'); 
$('.item').last().addClass('last');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Chapabu, I found out why my jQuery didn't work. I should have moved the `<script>` to end of the page.

Comment: @Jake Or wrap it in `jQuery(function() { ... });`